# Недостатки обобщенных типов в C#

Tags: c#, c++, generics

Хотелось бы задать такой вопрос: неоднократно слышал, что обобщенные типы (generics) в C# менее мощны, нежели шаблоны в C++. Но вот каких-либо доводов в пользу (или против) этого утверждения я не слышал. Действительно ли это так, если да, то в чем именно это  проявляется.

P.S. От себя могу лишь добавить, что недавно столкнулся с такой досадной и странной  особенностью, что если `SomeClassChild` — потомок класса `SomeClass`, то 
`List<SomeClassChild>` нельзя преобразовать к `List<SomeClass>`, тогда как `SomeClassChild[]` к `SomeClass[]` — можно.

Более того, следующий код также приведет к ошибке:

```
List<SomeClass> lst = new List<SomeClass>();
lst.Add(new SomeClassChild());
```

Comment: [Differences Between C++ Templates and C# Generics](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/c6cyy67b.aspx)

Comment: @DreamChild

- Ваше второе утверждение неверно для любых версий `.NET,` где есть дженерики (т.е начиная с `.NET 2.0`).

- Вариант с `IList<Child> ---> IList<Parent>` поддерживается в `C# 4+` на уровне интерфейсов. См. [**How is Generic Covariance & Contra-variance Implemented in C# 4.0?**](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/245607/how-is-generic-covariance-contra-variance-implemented-in-c-sharp-4-0).

Comment: @Котик: вы уверены, что IList, а не IEnumerable? IList<T> [не ковариантен](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/5y536ey6.aspx) по T

Comment: @VladD Да, ошибся - забыл, что для мутабельных коллекций ковариантной преобразование небезопасно. Спасибо.

Comment: Шаблоны в плюсах - это не просто механизм для создания обобщенных типов, а целый полный по Тьюрингу мини-язык =)

Answer (score 30, accepted):

Разница на самом деле большая.

Шаблоны C++ -- продвинутая версия макросов. В C# же генерики -- конструкция времени выполнения. Это определяет разницу. Например, такое:

```
template<typename T>
T add(T lhs, T rhs)
{
    return lhs + rhs;
}
```

проходит в C++: во время компиляции шаблона компилятор точно знает тип T и знает, может ли к нему применяться оператор +. Аналогичная конструкция не сработает в C#: компилятор генерирует один код для всех на все случаи, и он не знает, что такое + для произвольных классов. Можно, конечно, обойти проверку при помощи такого трюка:

```
T add<T>(T lhs, T rhs)
{
    dynamic l = lhs;
    dynamic r = rhs;
    return (T)(l + r);
}
```

-- но эта конструкция выявит отсутствие оператора + во время выполнения, а не компиляции.

---

Из того, что генерики -- конструкция времени выполнения, выплывают и другие отличия. В частности, в генериках, в отличие от шаблонов C++, нельзя сделать отдельную специализацию для конкретного типа параметров, или для некоторого их набора. (Для шаблонов это называется "частичная/явная специализация".)

---

Теперь по поводу вашего примера:

```
List<SomeClassChild> lderived = new List<SomeClassChild>();
List<SomeClass> lbase = lderived; // не компилируется
```

То, что приведённая строка не компилируется -- правильно. И не должно.

Представьте себе, что этот код таки скомпилировался. Тогда вы сможете написать:

```
lbase.Add(new SomeClass());
```

А это уже плохо, потому что теперь в `lderived` появился экземпляр чужого класса! То, что `SomeClassChild[]` можно привести к `SomeClass[]` -- это "тяжёлое наследие" старых версий языка, когда не была реализована ковариантность генериков. (Вставить элемент чужого класса всё равно на получится, вылетит с исключением.)

---

По поводу

```
List<SomeClass> lst = new List<SomeClass>();
lst.Add(new SomeClassChild());
```

-- это должно работать. Перепроверьте!

---

Следует отметить, что у генериков C# есть и преимущества по сравнению с C++. Например, код генерика один и тот же для всех специализаций (на уровне IL, JIT-компилятор может ради оптимизации сделать несколько разных специализаций на уровне нативного кода). Поэтому вы можете компилировать код, использующий генерик, даже не имея полного исходного текста генерика. Для шаблонов C++ это невозможно: шаблон должен быть перекомпилирован для каждого из типов, с которым он используется. Эта особенность существенно замедляет компиляцию шаблонов в C++ по сравнению с C#, где генерик компилируется лишь один раз.

---

Дополнение: поскольку в C++ **все** инстанциации шаблона должны быть известны во время компиляции, это не позволяет динамически решать, с каким типом будет инстанциирован шаблон (что ограничивает семантику программ). У C# инстанциация шаблона происходит во время выполнения, и проблем не возникает. Пример: [C#](http://ideone.com/s7CR1M), [C++](http://ideone.com/5nFp3n).

Comment: большое спасибо, очень помогли. А во втором примере я действительно ошибся, прощу прощения

Comment: и еще, если несложно: 
вы привели следующий способ обойти ограничение невозможности использования операторов:
    T add<T>(T lhs, T rhs)
    {
        dynamic l = lhs;
        dynamic r = rhs;
        return (T)(l + r);
    }
не принимая во внимание, что для типа T может быть не определен оператор "+", насколько сильно повлияет такой трюк на производительность? очевидно, это вариант будет проигрывать по производительности обычному сложению, но насколько?

Comment: @DreamChild: В принципе, проигрывать будет в основном при первом пробеге. Дальше рантайм закеширует результаты, и будет вызывать нужную функцию. То есть за исключением первого раза, расходы примерно такие же, как на вызов делегата.

Comment: @DreamChild: пожалуйста!

Comment: Хотелось бы услышать комментарий поставившего минус.

Comment: Не понимаю почему 
    List<SomeClassChild> lderived = new List<SomeClassChild>();
    List<SomeClass> lbase = lderived; // не компилируется

не компилируется. Вроде ж должно же, идеологически же все верно. SomeClassChild is-a SomeClass. По идее должно все кошерно кастится. (зы. минус не я ставил, если чё).

Comment: @SoloMio на самом деле это какая-то моя ошибка - приведенный код вполне компилируется, там должен был быть какой-то другой. Но какой - за давностью лет не помню

Comment: @SoloMio: дело вот в чём: несмотря на то, что `SomeChildClass` is-a `SomeClass`, `List<SomeChildClass>` не есть is-a `List<SomeClass>`. Причины этого описаны в ответе.

Как верно заметил @Котик_хочет_кушать,

> для мутабельных коллекций ковариантное преобразование небезопасно

Comment: "Из того, что генерики -- конструкция времени выполнения" и "У C# инстанциация шаблона происходит во время выполнения" - это не совсем правда. Там по сути нет понятия инстанциации, generic работает с тем, что известно на этапе компиляции (ну если там dynamic нигде нет).

Comment: @Qwertiy: Эхм. А вы заглядывали в примеры по ссылкам? То, что генерики существуют во время выполнения, подтверждается хотя бы наличием API: `https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.type.makegenerictype%28v=vs.110%29.aspx`. С этим вы сможете конструировать типы, о которых во время компиляции ничего не известно. (В отличие от C++.)

Comment: @Qwertiy: О том, что генерик-типы инстанциируются в рантайме, и были два примера. C++ пытался резрезольвить типы в compile-time, что и привело к бесконечному циклу. C# так делать не пытается, иначе у него была бы та же самая проблема.

Comment: @VladD, там не такой compile-time. Сейчас сделаю пример.

Comment: @VladD, вот, сделал пример: http://ideone.com/SfnNff - компилятор уже при компиляции знает, что он вызывает. Да, полиморфизм виртуальных методов работает, но в самом коде нет инстанциирования и выявления метода в рантайме.

Comment: @VladD, решил написать подробный ответ: http://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/167906/%D0%9D%D0%B5%D0%B4%D0%BE%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%BA%D0%B8-%D0%BE%D0%B1%D0%BE%D0%B1%D1%89%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%BD%D1%8B%D1%85-%D1%82%D0%B8%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%B2-%D0%B2-c/416985#416985

Comment: @DreamChild, вариант с рефлексией будет сильно проигрывать. Каждый раз будет делаться определение типа, выявление нужного метода и его вызов при помощи рефлексии, что ещё и боксинг-анбоксинг может спровоцировать. И с большой вероятностью кешироваться ничего не будет - всё в полной мере будет происходить при каждом вызове.

Comment: @Qwertiy: Тем не менее, в коде на C++ **невозможно** инстанциировать template по типу, не известному на этапе компиляции шаблона. Вы даже не можете инстанциировать шаблон, не включив его полное описание. У C# этой проблемы нету. Так что шаблон — это по существу синтаксический сахар над макросами. (Окей, больше, чем сахар, но ненамного.)

Comment: @VladD, в Си++ шаблоны координально отличаются от макросов. Ладно, вопрос не об этом. Да, в Си++ тип должен быть известен. Нет, C# не решает эту "проблему". "Шаблон" в шарпе - это просто функция - обычная функция, которая будет исполняться так, как ей предписано, независимо от реального типа. Все вызовы строятся на основе объявленных ограничений на generic-тип. Реальный тип кикак не используется.

Comment: @Qwertiy: Не вижу кардинального _семантического_ различия макросов и шаблонов, только различия на уровне парсера. Шаблоны, как и макросы, существуют лишь на этапе компиляции, и не могут компилироваться в отрыве от подставляемого типа. Генерики существуют и без подставляемого типа.

Comment: @VladD, про существование только на этапе компиляции согласен. Но тем не менее, весьма существенная разница между шаблонами и макросами есть. Макросы - это часть кода - вего лишь фрагмент, более того, любой фрагмент, возможно он даже не компилируется сам по себе синтаксически, а только в вызывающем контексте корректен. А шаблон - это законченная функция, да, она будет создана под конкретный тип, но она функция, она не способна затрагивать синтаксис языка. Только макрос можно вызвать так `DO_SMTH(},{, ,for)` - для этого невозможно сделать эквивалент на основе шаблона.

Comment: @Qwertiy: Насчёт «не решает», вы вполне можете объявить класс `List<YourType>` не видя описания `List<>`.

Comment: @Qwertiy: Ну да, согласен, немного погорячился. Не аналогичны. Но всё же, и тот и другой — метапрограммирование на уровне синтаксического дерева, не глубже.

Comment: @VladD, не понял пример с `List<YourType>`. Что вообще подразумевается под `List<>`?

Comment: @Qwertiy: `System.Collections.Generic.List<T>`. У вас есть откомпилированный модуль, уже содержащий этот generic-тип. Тем не менее, вы не имея исходника можете скомпилировать и проинстанциировать `List<YourClass>`.

Comment: @Qwertiy: Вы можете написать на C# функцию, которая делает вот что: она читает имя типа с консоли, и инстанциирует `List<X>`, где X — этот самый тип. То есть, инстанцияция генерика с типом, не известным на момент компиляции. На C++ это не пройдёт. /// Или например, вы не сможете на C++ сделать аналог вот этого: http://ideone.com/s7CR1M

Answer (score 7):

Шаблоны в Си++ компилируются под каждый конкретный аргумент в новый кусок кода. Это позволяет использовать в них в полной мере все возможности того типа, который в них подставлен.

Генерики в C# компилируются в код, который может быть применён для любого переданного в них типа (подходящего под объявленное условие). Из-за этого сразу **теряются** следующие возможности:

- Использование статических методов генерик-типа, а следовательно всех операторов (кроме default property, конечно). Есдинственное исключение сделано для new без параметров. И то он вызывается рефлексией, поскольку другого способа в .net-рантайме нет.
- Возможность наследоваться от генерик-параметра.
- Возможность использовать какие-либо методы, наличие которых не гарантируется перечисленными в where ограничениями на классы и интерфейсы.

Шаблоны в C# компилируются в код, подходящий под любой допустимый параметр. Т. е. шаблон в шарпе - это просто функция - обычная функция, которая будет исполняться так, как ей предписано, независимо от реального типа. Все вызовы строятся на основе объявленных ограничений на generic-тип. Реальный тип кикак не используется. Поэтому **по-другому работают** такие вещи как:

- Вызов невиртуальных методов и методов интерфейса. Вызывается метод базового класса, а не реального, как было бы в Си++.
  http://ideone.com/SfnNff
- Разрешение перегрузки функций происходит во время компиляции, когда сведения о конкретном типе неизвестны.
  http://ideone.com/DKCu9V

Вроде было ещё что-то, но сейчас не могу вспомнить.

Answer (score 4):

Ещё одно преимущество шаблонов C++ заключается в том, что они позволяют параметризовать функцию или класс не только типом, но и значением. Ещё в последней версии C++ появились шаблоны с переменным числом параметров.