# Оператор вида ">" не может применяться к операндам вида <T> и <T>

Tags: c#, .net, generics

Надо написать функцию, которая выполняет какую-нибудь логическую операцию над двумя операндами в соответствии с той операцией, которая занесена в строку.
Я попытался сделать как ниже, но так не получилось. Помогите пожалуйста.

```
private bool cmpStr<T>(string s, T c1, T c2)
{
    if (s == ">") return c1 > c2;
    else if (s == ">=") return c1 >= c2;
    else if (s == "==") return c1 == c2;
    else if (s == "<=") return c1 <= c2;
    else if (s == "<") return c1 < c2;
    else return false;
}
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Недостатки обобщенных типов в C#](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/167906/%d0%9d%d0%b5%d0%b4%d0%be%d1%81%d1%82%d0%b0%d1%82%d0%ba%d0%b8-%d0%be%d0%b1%d0%be%d0%b1%d1%89%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%bd%d1%8b%d1%85-%d1%82%d0%b8%d0%bf%d0%be%d0%b2-%d0%b2-c)

Comment: @PashaPash нет.

Comment: @andreycha первая же строчка в ответе Vlad - невозможность использовать +, (и поставить констрейнт на это). Но если между + и < такая огромная разница - тогда ок - нет :)

Comment: @PashaPash у человека возник конкретный вопрос. Ему были даны три конкретных ответа, которые разъясняют проблему и предлагают способы решения. Оригинальный вопрос автору не помог бы.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Дело в том, что при таком объявлении:

```
cmpStr<T>(string s, T c1, T c2)
```

в метод могут быть переданы аргументы *любого* типа. При этом *все* операции, которые проводятся в методе с аргументами, должны поддерживаться типом этого аргумента. А любой ли тип поддерживает операции <, >, <=, >=? Нет, не любой. Поэтому такой код некорректен.

Чтобы код работал, на параметр-тип `Т` нужно наложить ограничение: чтобы `Т` был такого типа (или его подтипом), который поддерживает нужные вам операции. Как вариант вы можете ввести некоторый тип (например, `MyType`), в котором будут переопределены эти операции. А дальше указать ограничение:

```
cmpStr<T>(string s, T c1, T c2) where T : MyType
```

`MyType` при этом может быть оберткой:

```
public class MyType 
{
    public int Value;

    public static bool operator <(MyType  a1, MyType a2)
    {
        return a1.Value < a2.Value;
    }

    public static bool operator >(MyType a1, MyType a2)
    {
        return a1.Value > a2.Value;
    }

    ...
}
```

(При этом мы наталкиваемся на новую проблему: `Value` тоже хочется сделать дженерик, а нельзя. Замкнутый круг.)

Также `MyType` может не являться оберткой, а содержать свою логику.

---

Таков общий ответ. Проясните свою задачу, и я конкретизирую ответ.

---

P.S. Напоследок пара ссылок на альтернативные решения:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/18875731/1985167
http://www.yoda.arachsys.com/csharp/miscutil/usage/genericoperators.html

Comment: Спасибо за ответ. Как я понял, гораздо проще переписать эту функцию дважды :)

Comment: @Nikita_Rabykin расскажите, какую задачу вы решаете. Почему дважды?

Comment: Я хотел сделать что-то такое: http://pastebin.com/STKBa6Jq 
То есть сравнить 2 переменные простого типа, используя строку как оператор.

Answer (score 5):

Используйте ограничение `IComparable` или `IComparable<T>` - что позволит вам использовать метод `Compare`, сделанный специально для таких ситуаций. Также можно принимать `IComparer<T>` отдельным аргументом - тогда ограничение не потребуется.

Теперь вы можете переписать ваш код так:

```
private bool cmpStr<T>(string s, T c1, T c2) where T : IComparable<T>
{
    if (s == ">") return c1.Compare(c2) > 0;
    else if (s == ">=") return c1.Compare(c2) >= 0;
    else if (s == "==") return c1.Compare(c2) == 0;
    else if (s == "<=") return c1.Compare(c2) <= 0;
    else if (s == "<") return c1.Compare(c2) < 0;
    else return false;
}

private bool cmpStr<T>(string s, T c1, T c2, IComparer<T> comparer)
{
    if (s == ">") return comparer.Compare(c1, c2) > 0;
    else if (s == ">=") return comparer.Compare(c1, c2) >= 0;
    else if (s == "==") return comparer.Compare(c1, c2) == 0;
    else if (s == "<=") return comparer.Compare(c1, c2) <= 0;
    else if (s == "<") return comparer.Compare(c1, c2) < 0;
    else return false;
}
```

Главное достоинство такого подхода - все упорядоченные примитивные типы уже реализуют этот интерфейс.

Answer (score 2):

Я бы сделал это, так, ограничив тип T интерфейсом IComparable:

```
private bool cmpStr<T>(string s, T c1, T c2) 
                            where T : IComparable<T>
{
    int res = c1.CompareTo(c2);

    switch (s)
    {
        case ">":                
            return res > 0;
        case ">=":
            return res >= 0;
        case "==":
            return res == 0;
        case "<=":
            return res <= 0;
        case "<":
            return res < 0;
        default:
            throw new ArgumentException();
    }        
}
```

Числовые типы этот интерфейс поддерживают