# Классы и объекты в C#?

Tags: c#, clr

Подскажите, пожалуйста.

1. При создании экземпляра класса в C# выделяется память под него в управляемой куче, он может хранить в себе только не статические поля класса - это понятно, а где же хранятся методы и статика? На одном курсе на youtube смотрел видео, где человек рассказывал, что методы и статика хранится в объекте, но ведь я полагал, что экземпляр и объект одно и тоже?
2. В Интерфейсе обязательно все методы реализовывать?

Comment: Хоть бы ссылку дал, что смотрел. Желательно, с привязкой ко времени.

Comment: «Хранятся в объекте» — это с логической точки зрения. А физически они могут быть расположены где угодно.

Comment: с каких пор в интерфейсе нужно реализовывать методы? методы можно объявить, но никакой реализации.
класс, наследующий интерфейс, должен реализовать его методы

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Если коротко, есть объект-тип, и экземпляр объекта, который имеет ссылку на объект-тип. Они оба находятся в куче. Статические поля находятся в составе объекта-типа. Объект тип всегда один, и он так же находится в куче.

Подробно про это можно узнать в книге Рихтер Дж. CLR via C#. Программирование на платформе Microsoft .NET. в 4 главе.

Answer (score 17):

Смотрите. Для начала, *с точки зрения языка* совершенно неважно, где именно хранятся переменные. Главное, чтобы они были доступны и имели правильную длину жизненного цикла. Вообще, само понятие стека и кучи [не имеет особого смысла](https://ericlippert.com/2009/04/27/the-stack-is-an-implementation-detail-part-one/).

Теперь, с точки зрения имплементации в текущей версии Microsoft CLR, вопрос имеет смысл. Действительно, есть многие вспомогательные объекты, которые возникают во время работы программы. Например, статические переменные, объекты типов и тому подобное. Статические переменные располагаются в специальной области памяти, которая не доступна сборщику мусора, и с точки зрения ОС является кучей. (Эта область памяти называется «high frequency heap».)

Заметьте, что расположить статические переменные *статическим образом*, выделив под них память на этапе компиляции, невозможно по многим причинам. Например, для такого generic-класса на C#

```
class C<T>
{
    static T t;
}
```

тип статической переменной (а значит, и его размер) неизвестен во время компиляции. Кроме того, потенциальное количество разных `T`, с которыми будет инстанциирован `C`, бесконечно, и их список нельзя определить при помощи статического анализа (потому что в отличие от шаблонов C++, в .NET, список инстанциаций generic-типа не определяется на этапе компиляции, см. последний абзац [здесь](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/167921/10105)).

По поводу того, где хранятся методы в CLR — а где хранятся методы обыкновенных, нативных классов? В .NET все методы хранятся в IL-виде до пробега JIT (но не в .NET Native!), JIT при компиляции метода аллоцирует память для нативного кода.

---

По поводу второго пункта — да, если вы имеете в виду класс, реализующий интерфейс. Наоборот, если вы определяете интерфейс, то никаких методов при этом не реализуете. А какую вы видите альтернативу?

Comment: "Вообще, само понятие стека и кучи не имеет особого смысла." Аллилуйя! После хождений по собеседованиям я уж думал один только так думаю. Это ж все детали имплементации, все верно...

Comment: @hardsky: Такое же мнение у Эрика Липперта, так что вы не один.

Answer (score 11):

В .NET есть несколько управляемых куч.

Память для самих объектов и для нестатических свойств выделяется

- в Small Objects Heap - с тремя поколениями и сборкой мусора методом перекладыванием объектов поплотнее.
- или в Large Objects Heap без поколений, для больших объектов, без поколений и уплотнения (по умолчанию).

эти куски памяти общие для всего приложения.

Статические же поля - не общие для всего приложения. Они общие для всех объектов в пределах одного AppDomain. Поэтому и хранятся они не в общей SOH или LOH. А в одной из куч, выделяемых специально для объектов текущего домена - HighFrequencyHeap.

В ней же хранятся другие специфичексие для каждого домена вещи - MethodTable-ы, MethodDesc-и, FieldDesc-и, карты интерфейсов.

Т.е. чисто физически статика лежит не в каком-то конкретном экземпляре, и не где-то "в классе", а в отдельной песочнице для каждого домена.

Кроме HFH у каждого домена есть еще своя LowFrequencyHeap - EEClass-ы, данные ClassLoader-а и прочие вещи, доступ к которым требуется достаточно редко.

Подробно о механизме создания объектов и о том, как выделяется память можно почитать в [статье Drill Into .NET Framework Internals to See How the CLR Creates Runtime Objects
, MSDN Magazine за май 2005](http://download.microsoft.com/download/3/a/7/3a7fa450-1f33-41f7-9e6d-3aa95b5a6aea/MSDNMagazineMay2005en-us.chm) - не забудьте разблокировать файл в проводнике после закачки. Раньше статья была доступна на [сайте MSDN Magazine](https://msdn.microsoft.com/magazine/ee310108), но в какой-то момент ее оттуда убрали, а [веб-архив с ней](https://web.archive.org/web/20140724084944/http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc163791.aspx) из России забанен.

---

2 - да.

Answer (score 4):

1. Нет, в экземпляре они точно не хранятся.
2. Да, класс, реализующий некоторый интерфейс, обязан реализовать все его методы.
   Однако, возможно использовать явную реализацию интерфейса, чтобы скрыть эти методы из списка методов класса.

Comment: в .NET интерфейс может реализовывать методы?

Comment: @Александр, я имел в виду не это. Уточнил. А вообще, в .net'е (но не в C#) интерфейс может _содержать реализованные статические методы_.

Comment: теперь понятно )

Answer (score 4):

1. статические методы и поля хранятся в обьекте который создается на куче при первой инициализации экземпляра класса. Нестатические методы и поля хранятся в экземпляре класса на то й же куче.
2. при реализации интерфейса нужно реализовать все методы и поля. Только не в интерфейсе а в классе который его реализует путем наследования

Answer (score 4):

Хотелось бы еще добавить то, что интерфейс это просто контракт. Это гарантия того, что у некоторого объекта есть определенные методы (свойства и т.п.) и не важно откуда они взялись. Т.е. они могут быть как реализованы явно, так и получены путем наследования, например:

```
public class A 
{
  public void Do()
  {
    Console.WriteLine("Do");
  }
}

public interface IDo
{
  void Do();
}

public class B : A, IDo
{
}
```

Comment: ... в отличие от C++, кажется (с заменой интерфейса на абстрактный класс).