# В чем разница между обобщенными классами в C++ и Java/c#/delphi?

Tags: java, c++, delphi

В чем разница между обобщенными классами в C++ и Java/c#/delphi?

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/167906/10105

Comment: [Объясните разницу между шаблонами в C++ и дженериками в Java](https://tproger.ru/problems/explain-the-difference-between-the-patterns-in-c-and-c-and-generalizations). Если коротко, то в С++ нет обобщённых (generic) классов, там есть шаблоны (template) классов. На основе шаблонов компилятор генерирует классы для каждого типа.

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Недостатки обобщенных типов в C#](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/167906/%d0%9d%d0%b5%d0%b4%d0%be%d1%81%d1%82%d0%b0%d1%82%d0%ba%d0%b8-%d0%be%d0%b1%d0%be%d0%b1%d1%89%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%bd%d1%8b%d1%85-%d1%82%d0%b8%d0%bf%d0%be%d0%b2-%d0%b2-c)

Answer (score -3, accepted):

Если не рассматривать синтаксические особенности, то главное различие обобщенных классов в C++ и Java/C#/Delphi состоит в том, что C++ должен знать тип объектной переменной (экземпляра) во время компиляции. Остальные перечисленные языки определяют тип в рантайме, то есть во время выполнения программы.

Например, в C++ при создании контейнеров из STL всегда требуется указать тип будущего содержимого: `std::vector<тип данных> myVector;`

Comment: что значит _Остальные перечисленные языки определяют тип в рантайме_ ? Пример для C++ актуален и для C#.

Comment: @Grundy C++ требует чтобы тип будущей объектной переменной был определен на этапе компиляции, без этого программа банально не соберется. Тогда как остальные перечисленные выше языки обходятся без этого, подставляя типы в рантайме

Comment: У java есть определенные типы. Да, по сути там один большой Object и можно все к нему сводить, но типы на этапе компиляции проверяются

Comment: @Mister_Jesus Если бы всё идеально проверялось, то не было бы исключений. Вот простой пример:

```String[] strings = new String[] {"a", "b", "c"};
Object[] arr = strings;
arr[0] = 42; // ArrayStoreException. Проблема обнаружилась на этапе выполнения программы```

Comment: @ЛитералМрачности: Ваш пример о другом, он о ковариантности массивов, уродливом наследии отсутствия дженериков в первых версиях Java.

Comment: @VladD Я извиняюсь, если пример не совсем корректный. Но во всех материалах которые я видел, а это в первую очередь институт, а уже потом статьи - везде говорится о том, что типы в Java/C#/Delphi подставляются в рантайме.

Comment: @ЛитералМрачности: это да, у меня даже в самом конце [этого ответа](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/167921/10105) есть забавный пример по этому поводу.